# How to open and keep session from AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.6

- How to open and keep session to a specific web server from AIR application ?

so far i tried this way, but no luck :

```
var qHeader    : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader();


            var urlRequest : URLRequest  = new URLRequest( requestTarget.text );                    
                urlRequest.method        = URLRequestMethod.POST;   
                urlRequest.data          = cookiesObject;
                //urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( qHeader );
                urlRequest.requestHeaders = new Array( "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=u43mjnpuerdicmu5pjobi2dz" )

            var rr : Response = new Response();

            //URLRequestDefaults.manageCookies = true;

            var _urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                _urlLoader.dataFormat  = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;



                _urlLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onReceive );
                _urlLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFail );

            _urlLoader.load( urlRequest );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request header must be a `URLRequestHeader` object. Try this:

```
urlRequest.requestHeaders = new Array(new URLRequestHeader("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=u43mjnpuerdicmu5pjobi2dz"));
```